# Rendering bug with IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, rendering, internet-explorer-11

I seem to have come across a rendering bug in Internet Explorer.  Here's a sample page that will cause the bug in IE11:

http://pastebin.com/J2pJ7qaY

The bug can be seen from this rendered screenshot:

[image: Rendering of problem]

Basically the first of the two DIVs has a `right:0px` style whereas the second one has a fixed width.  For some reason the former causes the "Completed" table header to be rendered incorrectly (it works fine in all other browser as far as I can tell).

Does anyone know why this rendering bug happens and how to fix it?

Comment: inspect it with IE's debug tools and see what the computed css rule(s) are on it.

Comment: For the table header cell that's too short?  Its styling (including height) seems to be the same as the other one.